# Find the class name by matching content within a div tag (regex/php)

Tags: php, regex

Here is my problem...

Based on the code below... I need a PHP script which uses Regex or some other way to extract the name of the div class which contains the text: **TEXT1**.
In this case, return of the script should be: **CLASSNAME_3**

```
 <div class="CLASSNAME_1">
  <span class="CLASSNAME_2"></span>
   <div class="CLASSNAME_3">
   TEXT1
   </div>
 </div>
```

Reason for the script is, that the name of the class (CLASSNAME_3) is constantly changing, while the content of the class (TEXT1) is not.

I've researched this all over the web and also on stackoverflow, but I am unable to find the answer, nor any similar question which could help me to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be possible through positive lookahead.

```
/\"([^"]*)(?=\">\s*TEXT1)/gm
```

It matches `CLASSNAME_3` because it is followed by the string `TEXT1`.

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/vH8oG1)

Comment: +1 for nice work on the regex, Avinash, but you have a typo in the explanation: your regex actually doesn't need `DOTALL` to work... There are no dots! :)

Comment: +1 your answer has cleared my doubts about lookahead, though @zx81 send me a link about this but still I had some doubts and they are clear now. Thanks to  you too @_zx81 will also follow lookbehind concept. :)

Comment: @HarpreetSingh lookbehind and lookahead options play a major role in regex. If you have any doubts just get into regex chatroom and ask questions about that.